# Querybuilder in AEM 6.2 returning different result than AEM6.0

Tags: adobe, aem, query-builder

We are working on moving some projects from AEM 6.0 and 6.2 one of the applications has an error and documentation hasn't been helpful.her is the reduced case querybuilder query

```
type=cq:page
path=/content/nera/en/experts
p.hits=full
p.nodedepth=1
1_property.opertaion=like
1_property=jcr:content/jcr:title
1_property.value=Dr.
```

The issue is that even though the operation is set to like only full matches are returned. partial matches return no results however on AEM 6.0 partial results are returned. In my case the value of "Dr." returns nothing while Dr. Lawrence Wu which is an existing node returns the page.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Small comment I tried using the % as wildcard so the last line would be
    1_property.value=%Dr.%

Comment: Are you using a custom index or default indexes? ACS Explain query tool can help you find the index that was used and you can check aggregation property rulese on it. It has to be full text index for your desired results. Seems like you are hitting a property index.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo or probably an error in your sample/code:

1_property.**opertaion**=like

instead of:

```
1_property.operation=like
```

Beside this, I don't thing that there is any difference in the QueryBuilder implementation between 6.0 and 6.2. All query builder queries are converted to SQL2 before they are executed. You can set the log level to DEBUG for the following packages in order to see the actual queries in your log:

- org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query
- com.day.cq.search

You can also test your queries using the [query debug servlet](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html) and see what xpath is produced in the end. The option `p.hits=full` controls only if all properties are included in the result or just a small set of them (e.g. path, name, title, etc.)